# Parse EC Public Key with pyasn1

Tags: python-2.7, asn.1, ecdsa

How to parse ec public with the use of pyasn1?

```
    from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder
    import base64
    raw2='''
    MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE/FU6/Om2m5EnxDwGSVO+YNXorpDtzutLtCAMTZR5
    NIs6pfKx9oyjpS5aURx4BinuW8dr8K7N2oafY1TNvc41oQ==
    '''
    der = decoder.decode(base64.b64decode(raw2))
    print der
    '''
     der:
    (Sequence().setComponentByPosition(0, Sequence().setComponentByPosition(0, ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.10045.2.1)).setComponentByPosition(1, ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.10045.3.1.7))).setComponentByPosition(1, BitString("'0000010011111100010101010011101011111100111010011011011010011011100100010010011111000100001111000000011001001001010100111011111001100000110101011110100010101110100100001110110111001110111010110100101110110100001000000000110001001101100101000111100100110100100010110011101010100101111100101011000111110110100011001010001110100101001011100101101001010001000111000111100000000110001010011110111001011011110001110110101111110000101011101100110111011010100001101001111101100011010101001100110110111101110011100011010110100001'B")), '')
'''
```

Is it possible, to get something like [this](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#3059301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D0301070342000486B3CA908BD0C530EED8B9E273F48783EC1836E0687EE73EAAF7EDEA60365B6D8A4CC369201E835D78383F298AB5979A59A5C6B207DAB44A25A9083E24C4FC56) with pyasn1.

**Edit:**
I base myself on [this](http://pydoc.net/Python/pyXMLSecurity/0.4/xmlsec.rsa_x509_pem.x509_pem/) to obtain the following:

```
class curve(univ.Sequence):

    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
     namedtype.NamedType('public KeyType',univ.ObjectIdentifier()),
     namedtype.NamedType('curveName',univ.ObjectIdentifier())
    )

class EcPublicKey(univ.Sequence):
  componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.NamedType('curve', curve()),
    namedtype.NamedType('publicKeyValue', univ.BitString())
    )

pubKey,rest = decoder.decode(base64.b64decode(raw2), asn1Spec = EcPublicKey())

print(pubKey.prettyPrint())
'''
EcPublicKey:
 curve=curve:
  public KeyType=1.2.840.10045.2.1
  curveName=1.2.840.10045.3.1.7

 publicKeyValue="'0000010011111100010101010011101011111100111010011011011010011011100100010010011111000100001111000000011001001001010100111011111001100000110101011110100010101110100100001110110111001110111010110100101110110100001000000000110001001101100101000111100100110100100010110011101010100101111100101011000111110110100011001010001110100101001011100101101001010001000111000111100000000110001010011110111001011011110001110110101111110000101011101100110111011010100001101001111101100011010101001100110110111101110011100011010110100001'B"

'''
```

Answer (score 2):

repr() gives you Python code which would produce the same object(s) once evaluated. For a  human-oriented representation use .prettyPrint() method (of any pyasn1 object):

```
publicKey, restOfInput = decoder.decode(base64.b64decode(raw2))
print publicKey.prettyPrint()
```

Sequence:
 <no-name>=Sequence:
 <no-name>=1.2.840.10045.2.1
 <no-name>=1.2.840.10045.3.1.7

<no-name>="'0000010011111100010101010011101011111100111010011011011010011011100100010010011111000100001111000000011001001001010100111011111001100000110101011110100010101110100100001110110111001110111010110100101110110100001000000000110001001101100101000111100100110100100010110011101010100101111100101011000111110110100011001010001110100101001011100101101001010001000111000111100000000110001010011110111001011011110001110110101111110000101011101100110111011010100001101001111101100011010101001100110110111101110011100011010110100001'B"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that pyasn1 doen't provide better formatting, so you will have to implement it yourself by following the pattern from `__repr__` method (see `AbstractSimpleAsn1Item` and `AbstractConstructedAsn1Item` from http://pyasn1.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyasn1/pyasn1/pyasn1/type/base.py?revision=1.35&view=markup)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have access to the value of the public key itself, you can use the [pycryptodome](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) library. Just format your data in the file public.pem:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE/FU6/Om2m5EnxDwGSVO+YNXorpDtzutLtCAMTZR5
NIs6pfKx9oyjpS5aURx4BinuW8dr8K7N2oafY1TNvc41oQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And then in Python:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import ECC
print(ECC.import_key(open('public.pem').read()))
```

EccKey(curve='P-256', x=114133426963296850915436792023241197556938624347236768937730916445384676553867, y=26527350004009046719864726291814153938182054558131723928772218772465776473505)